# Pass API object via Intent to Service?

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify, intentservice

I'm trying to send an object created from the Spotify API (a SpotifyAppRemote instance) from my MainActivity class to a BackgroundService (implemented as IntentService).
Since I can't use parcelable to send my object as I have no control over the API I was trying to use GSON to send it via the putExtra method from my intent like this:

```
intent.putExtra("spotifyRemote", gson.toJson(mSpotifyAppRemote, SpotifyAppRemote.class));
```

However, on runtime I get an error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: com.spotify.protocol.types.ImageUri. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

Is there another way to send this object to my Service? Looking for this error message didn't really help.

Here's the code from my MainActivity class:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(SpotifyAppRemote spotifyAppRemote) {
mSpotifyAppRemote = spotifyAppRemote;
getCurrentTrack();

// Now you can start interacting with App Remote
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        infoText.setText("Successfully started!");
        counter = 1;
        numSongs = Integer.parseInt(mEdit.getText().toString());
        PlayerApi playerApi = mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi();
        playerApi.seekTo(0);
        playerApi.resume();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);
        intent.putExtra("counter", counter);
        intent.putExtra("numSongs", numSongs);
        intent.putExtra("firstTrack", gson.toJson(curTrack, Track.class));
        intent.putExtra("spotifyRemote", gson.toJson(mSpotifyAppRemote, SpotifyAppRemote.class));

        startService(intent);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by declaring a static variable in my Service and setting the variable in my MainActivity like this:

```
BackgroundService.mSpotifyAppRemote = mSpotifyAppRemote;
```

Declaration in my Service:

```
public static SpotifyAppRemote mSpotifyAppRemote = null;
```